# Using Sundials CVODE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations, lapack, blas

I'm currently using ode15s to solve a set of stiff differential equations.
I am trying to use the MATLAB profiler to understand the section of the ode solver code which calls BLAS routines.

Since the instances in which BLAS routines are called by ode15s are not explicit, I want to use CVODE in Sundials solvers.

However, I am not sure how to use Sundials in MATLAB interface. `myodes` is the function which has the differential equations defined.

```
[t, species]  = ode15s(@(t,s) myodes(t,s), tspan , species0, options);
```

I would like to try solving the same set of odes using the CVODE solver, which calls BLAS Level 3 routies, in Sundials.

I checked some examples in MATLAB which show how to specify the solver type and use Sundials
https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/456467-simbiology-sundials-ode-solver-cvode?s_tid=sug_su
.

```
configsetObj = getconfigset(modelObj);
configsetObj.SolverType = 'sundials';
configsetObj.MaximumWallClock = 30;
configsetObj.MaximumNumberOfLogs = 100;
configsetObj.StopTime = 10;
[time, states] = sbiosimulate(modelObj);
plot(time,states)
```

I am not sure how to specify `modelObj`.

To directly use the CVODE using a C++ wrapper, I tried to download cvode-v6.6.0 from https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/sundials-software.

Suggestions on how to set up the CVODE solver interface in MATLAB will be of great help.

Comment: Any suggestions?